# How to retain only columns where a specific value is associated uniquely with another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks like this:

```
HH_ID  INDUSTRY       FREQUENCY 
102    CLERK           4
102    NURSE           2
102    NOT APPLICABLE  2
103    NURSE           3
103    NOT APPLICABLE  1  
104    NOT APPLICABLE  2
104    NOT APPLICABLE  1
```

I want to delete `NOT_APPLICABLE` only for those `HH_ID` which have another value, e.g. `CLERK` or `NURSE` associated to it. I want an output that looks something like this:

```
HH_ID   INDUSTRY       FREQUENCY
102     CLERK          4
102     NURSE          2
103     NURSE          3
104     NOT APPLICABLE 2
```

I want this above kind of output in R. I have tried data.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your data by `HH_ID` and subset each part to only contain those values you want to have in your data:

```
d <- data.frame(HH_ID = c(rep(102,3), 103, 103, 104, 104), INDUSTRY = factor(c('CLERK', 'NURSE', 'NOT APPLICABLE', 'NURSE', rep('NOT APPLICABLE', 3))), FREQUENCY = c(4,2,2,3,1,2,1))

library(plyr)
d2 <- ldply(split(d, d$HH_ID), function(d_tmp) {
    if(all(d_tmp$INDUSTRY == 'NOT APPLICABLE')) {
        d_tmp[1,]
    } else {
        d_tmp[d_tmp$INDUSTRY != 'NOT APPLICABLE',]
    }
})[,-1]
```

...which should be your desired data:

```
> print(d2)

  HH_ID       INDUSTRY FREQUENCY
1   102          CLERK         4
2   102          NURSE         2
3   103          NURSE         3
4   104 NOT APPLICABLE         2
```

PS: if there is only `NOT_APPLICABLE` associated with a certain `HH_ID` you seem to also want to collapse all instances of it to a single instance. If this is *not* true, exchange `d_tmp[1,]` with `d_tmp` in the `if(){...}` above.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# get a subset of the data that is different from "NOT APPLICABLE"
df1 <- df[INDUSTRY != "NOT APPLICABLE"]

# subset only "NOT APPLICABLE" rows where HH_ID is not present in df1 and keep only the row with highest FREQUENCY
df2 <- df[INDUSTRY == "NOT APPLICABLE"][!(HH_ID %in% df1$HH_ID)][max(FREQUENCY)]

# bind the two data sets
output <- rbind(df1, df2)

output 
#>    HH_ID       INDUSTRY FREQUENCY
#> 1:   102          CLERK         4
#> 2:   102          NURSE         2
#> 3:   103          NURSE         3
#> 4:   104 NOT APPLICABLE         2
```